# How to use SwipeRefresh layout ProgressBar circle

Tags: android, progress-bar, swiperefreshlayout

I would like to use this ProgressBar, instead of regular one, which is used in SwipeRefresh layout.

[image]

Is it part of v4 support or?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it programmatically

```
 mSwiperefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwiperefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        });
```

just use the above code where currenting you are calling the progressbar.

Comment: I ment use that pb instead of regular one independently of swiperef layout

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [sample app](https://github.com/TakeoffAndroid/MaterialCircleProgressBar)!
It provides the same custom progressbar which is there in swipe refresh layout...